# How to use WP-REST API to login user and get user data for Android app?

Tags: rest-api

I want to use Wordpress REST API to Login and get user data on android app.

I am using wp_users table for user and a custom table for user info .

I tried writing my own REST API but i for that i have to make $wpdb accessible outside Wordpress installation.

Please provide yours solution having API-KEY , or something similar  , feature too.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Comment: @shuvro , yes i have the solution , please check my answer. all the best with yours product

Comment: Have you read [this post on _make_](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/12/07/rest-api-tools-and-oauth/)?

Comment: man your solution was great but wordpress passwords are hashed :/ how did you log in ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the simplest solution using the WP-REST API  plugin,first set this in yours environment :

1.) In your themes `functions.php` register API endpoint hooks:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );
// API custom endpoints for WP-REST API
function register_api_hooks() {

    register_rest_route(
        'custom-plugin', '/login/',
        array(
            'methods'  => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'login',
        )
    );

    function login() {

        $output = array();

        // Your logic goes here.
        return $output;

    }
```

2.) By default, if you have pretty permalinks enabled, the WordPress REST API “lives” at /wp-json/. Then the API endpoint is accessible at `youdomain.com/wp-json/custom-plugin/login` with a `POST` request.

Notice that **custom-plugin/login** is actually defined in **register_rest_route** in PHP function **register_api_hooks()**

For API key I am using Wordpress Nonces -  [pretty straightforward as in my discussion here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/223816/92345) . I hope these answers are useful for all full stack developers who are new to Wordpress REST API

Comment: anyone looking for this functions.php file? Here it is -> wordpress\wp-content\themes\themeName\functions.php

Comment: I looks like that login function does nothing, what goes in // Your logic goes here ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to user login and get user details you can use and excellent plugin called "JSON API AUTH"

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/

There are following methods available: `validate_auth_cookie`, `generate_auth_cookie`, `clear_auth_cookie`, `get_currentuserinfo`

nonce can be created by calling `http://localhost/api/get_nonce/?controller=auth&method=generate_auth_cookie`

You can then use ‘nonce’ value to generate cookie. `http://localhost/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?nonce=f4320f4a67&username=Catherine&password=password-here`

Use cookie like this with your other controller calls: `http://localhost/api/contoller-name/method-name/?cookie=Catherine|1392018917|3ad7b9f1c5c2cccb569c8a82119ca4fd`